# React native - How to add 10 text inputs and get the total

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How is it possible to add 10 text inputs and get the total. 
Here is my code
10 text input may be a + value or - value

I just need the sum

```js
export default class App extends React.Component {
  renderTextBox(number) {
    let placeholder = 'GAME ' + number;
    return (
      <View style={styles.column} key="number">
        <TextInput keyboardType="numeric" key="number" placeholder={placeholder} underlineColorAndroid="transparent" style={styles.TextInputStyleClass} />
      </View>
    );
  }

  render() {
    let teamOneGames = [];
    let teamTwoGames = [];

    for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
      teamOneGames.push(this.renderTextBox(i));
      teamTwoGames.push(this.renderTextBox(i));
    }

    return (
     
<View style={{flexDirection: "row", height: "100%"}}>
  <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", backgroundColor: "#6dc6ed"}}>
    <Text>TEAM 1</Text>
    <TextInput  placeholder="ENTER NAME" underlineColorAndroid="transparent" style={styles.TextInputStyleClass} />
    <TextInput  placeholder="ENTER NAME" underlineColorAndroid="transparent" style={styles.TextInputStyleClass} />

    {teamOneGames}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **onChangeText** method for **TextInput** to get value for it. You do an operation on value. [Checkout this link for more info.](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html)

Example:

```
               <TextInput
                    style={Style.KEEPYOURSTYLE}
                    value={text}
                    onChangeText={(currentText) => {
                        // DO OPERATION ON currentText
                    }}
                />
```